# Is it possible to get notified when a page removes or hides a facebook application tab?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible for detect application uninstalls or if it's been hidden on a page without polling facebook?

Comment: No, that is not covered by real time updates.

Comment: That's the correct answer, i recommend adding it as one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. You'll need to poll the page to see if it's still installed and track it manually.